# How update a reference type in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with 2 fields an integer and a reference types

main 
    value : 10
    ref : products/9ci2hwiMUp63Q9Eugcqg

I want to change the field ref to `products/guEgu2sjsyOsSEChu2fT`. There is a class `DocumentReference` and the only attribute to change is a path but is read only attribute.

I read the documentation in firebase.google.com but not exist an example of how to update these type.

Is possible to update this type of field?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use UpdateData()  on Document Reference to Update data:

```
DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection('products').document('guEgu2sjsyOsSEChu2fT');
Map<String,dynamic> data = {
        'main value' : 10,
         'ref' : ref,  // Updating Document Reference 
        };

        Firestore.instance.collection('Your Collection Name').document('your document name').updateData(data).whenComplete((){
          print('Document Updated');
        });
```

Comment: This is valid only when the type is string. I got I/flutter ( 4535): Another exception was thrown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentReference'

Comment: Supported Types - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types 
check Reference type.

Comment: This is true Reference  By path elements (collection, document ID, collection, document ID...) but my question is related to How to update this kind of "Data type"